# PHP7 script crashes

Tags: php, php-7

I have a script which is running just fine in PHP 5.6, however it returns null in PHP 7. What could be the problem?

```
<?php

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($rs != false) {

    $event_array_all = array();
    if ($rs && mysqli_num_rows($rs)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

            $event_array[] = array(
                'id' => $row['CourtID'],
                'title' => $row['CourtName'],
                'eventColor' => '#428bca'
            );
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($event_array);
}
```

Thanks,
Goran

Comment: enabled error-reporting? `error_reporting(E_ALL);` ??

Comment: Shoudn't this `$event_array[] = array()` be `$event_array = array()`?

Comment: Make sure you've installed PHP7's MySQLi module.

Comment: If it echos NULL then that is the echo json_encode row. And why it does that is probably because event_array is empty. And the array is empty because the while and/or if statements are failing.

Comment: @Red if he does that, only the last row will be inserted in the variable...

Comment: @Red it's a valid way of writing, but it may or may not be correct. https://3v4l.org/9fgKK

Comment: @Anuga yeah, you are right. Hes looping through the result. Didn't notice so quikly.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)` Yes. A `MYSQL_` constant will help in another library.. It is undefined. Error reporting is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO - the main error is this

```
 mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

@Deepak Kumar T P, and other mentioned it, but I would just like to elaborate on it.

In PHP5.6   `MYSQL_ASSOC` = `MYSQLi_ASSOC` = `1`

In PHP7 `MYSQL_ASSOC` does not exist, so that throws either a warning (or notice) of Undefined constant assuming `'MYSQL_ASSOC'` which converts it to a string and then causes all kinds of issues.  So this typo, worked fine in 5.6 because both constants had the same value, however in PHP7 the typo was exposed because the other constant no longer exists.

So I wouldn't say this is an answer worthy of accepting, But it was more then I could add in a comment and I just wanted to clearly it a bit. So again thanks to @Deepak Kumar T P

Answer (score 1):

You should store in **$events_array_all** instead of **$event_array**
And also use **MYSQLI_ASSOC** instead of **MYSQL_ASSOC**

```
<?php

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ($rs != false) {

    $event_array_all = array();
    if ($rs && mysqli_num_rows($rs)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $event_array_all[] = array(
                'id' => $row['CourtID'],
                'title' => $row['CourtName'],
                'eventColor' => '#428bca'
            );
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($event_array_all);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. Wonder how `I have a script which is running just fine in PHP 5.6, however it returns null in PHP 7.` can be true. But I'm not sure this is the problem. In his code event array is used in the Json encode.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the `$event_array` is created on first loop and then rest is pushed into it.

Comment: But $event_array is never initialized as array

Comment: Doesn't need to be either. PHP doesn't need arrays to be created before used. You can `[]` and it will create and add value at the same time.

Comment: @Andreas - `Wonder how ... 5.6 not 7` because in 5.6 `MYSQLI_ASSOC = MYSQL_ASSOC = 1` in 7 MYSQL_ASSOC no longer exists so it is equal to a warning/notice and `'MYSQL_ASSOC'`

Comment: I wrote that comment earlier as an comment to the array _all thing. But yes. True.